# unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbReadTable’ for signature ‘"character", "missing"’

Tags: mysql, r

I am trying to read the table data in R with MySQL package.

Getting error:
**unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbReadTable’ for signature ‘"character", "missing"’**

code:

```
library(RMySQL)
library(dbConnect)
mydb = dbConnect(MySQL(), user='user',
             password='password', dbname='blank_copy',
             host='ip address', port = port_number)
dbListTables(mydb)
dbListFields(mydb, 'SELECT * FROM table_name')
dbReadTable("table_name")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the DBIConnection is missing

```
dbReadTable(mydb,"table_name")
```